# How to disable sourcemaps in Preact production build?

Tags: source-maps, preact

I haven't use preact before. tried a working method with react. seems it's not working with preact.

Comment: Source maps are something that your build tool outputs, while Preact and React are just UI libraries. They have nothing to do with source map generation. Need more information. What build tool are you using?

Comment: I'm using preact-cli. also found a solution for now. not sure is it the right way. however, it works. I removed the devtool config from the preact-cli webpack config. Thanks, though :)

Comment: Thanks. I'm one of preact-cli's maintainers, I wrote an answer for the correct way to go about disabling this below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this w/ Preact-CLI is to create (or edit) your `preact.config.js` like the following:

```js
// preact.config.js
export default (config, env, helpers) => {
  if (env.isProd) {
    config.devtool = false;
  }
}
```

We suggest this config (and others) in our config wiki, which you may want to take a look at: https://github.com/preactjs/preact-cli/wiki/Config-Recipes#disabling-source-maps-using-plugin-helpers